Login not working in lightdm (webkit2): "An error was detected in the current theme that could interfere with the system logic process"
I'm trying to make my own theme with lightdm-webkit2 but something seems to be failing and can't find what. I tried making the simplest example to make sure I can use it without problems. Here you have the html used:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>LightDM Theme</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="login-container">
        <form id="login-form" onsubmit="submitLogin(); return false;">
            <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
            <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

and the js:
function submitLogin() {
    const username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    lightdm.authenticate(username);
    lightdm.respond(password);
}

lightdm.authentication_complete = function() {
    if (lightdm.is_authenticated) {
        lightdm.start_session_sync(lightdm.default_session);
    } else {
        alert("Login failed");
    }
};

When trying to use it I see the correct html but when login it outputs this: "An error was detected in the current theme that could interfere with the system logic process".
The only thing that appeared in the terminal was:
** (WebKitWebProcess:2491): CRITICAL **: 20:32:01.055: lightdm_greeter_authenticate: assertion 'priv->connected' failed.
I am working on an arch linux os. If more logs are needed just tell me.
I don't find anything about this error (the one in the terminal) but someone saying that It can be fixed by downgrading lightdm, it didn't work. My current version is 1.32.
Thank you in advance.

I tried even to build it myself but still not working, here the repo: https://github.com/Antergos/web-greeter/tree/stable?tab=readme-ov-file
